# clojure, freeze after call future and same

Tags: concurrency, clojure

I have test script

```
(defn foo [] ( print "OK!" ))
(print "main")
(future-call foo)
(print "end")
```

When I run it in REPL, always fine

```
user=> (defn foo [] ( print "OK!" ))
#'user/foo
user=> (print "main")
mainnil
user=> (future-call foo)
OK!#<core$future_call$reify__6320@1d4997: nil>
user=> (print "end")
endnil
```

But when I run it from console, I have strange freeze after the code has finished executing

```
$ time clojure-1.6 /tmp/1.clj 
mainend
real    1m1.672s
user    0m2.229s
sys     0m0.143s
```

`mainend` displayed almost immediately, but returns to the shell takes about a minute.

pmap also work strange

```
(defn foo [x] ( print x ))
(print "main")
(pmap foo [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0])
(print "end")
```

will displayed

```
$ time clojure-1.6 /tmp/1.clj 
main12365409end
real    1m1.688s
user    0m2.320s
sys     0m0.114s
```

I known that `..365..` it's normal for concurrency code, but why 7 and 8 not displayed?

Comment: $ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (Gentoo package icedtea-7.2.5.5)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Clojure 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call shutdown-agents

> Note: If you leave out the call to (shutdown-agents), the program will on most (all?) OS/JVM combinations "hang" for 1 minute before the process exits.  It is waiting for a thread created by the future call to be shut down. shutdown-agents will shut them down immediately, or (System/exit ) will exit immediately without waiting for them to shut down.
>
> This wait occurs even if you use futures indirectly through some other Clojure functions that use them internally, such as pmap or clojure.java.shell/sh

From https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future

Comment: Thanks! Work fine. But some number still lost. When I call (shutdown-agents) it's right - thread not finished work and agent kill them. But why is this happening when agent don't call? Process should wait end thread,aren't?

Comment: You need to call shutdown-agents after the threads are done. There is no generic way for the vm to know if all the threads are ready for shutdown. If you need to run various future tasks and also have prompt shutdown, you need to ensure within your own application logic that all the threads have finished their work, then call `shutdown-agents`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, noisesmith!